# How to make update manager stop nagging about a new release?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I don't want to upgrade to the new release, and I don't want to have the notification icon about the upgrade (red triangle with exclamation mark in it) sit on the tray constantly.

Comment: See also related question http://askubuntu.com/questions/82681/how-to-stop-or-start-update-manager-from-startup for quelling the update notices in general, not only upgrades.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Open Update Manages and click on Settings .

[image]

- Go to Updates tab and change 'Show new distribution releases' to never.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the 'Software Sources' go to 'Updates' tab and set 'Show New Distribution Releases' to 'Never' as shown below. I use Natty but it will be same in Lucid and Maverick too.

[image: updates]

Answer (score 1):

You should go to software center --> edit--> software sources

Then on the third tab (updates) go to "release upgrade" (last one) and change it to "never"

edit : what the others said above with glorious images :D

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the GUI, in Precise another way to do it is to edit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades:

```
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
Prompt=lts
```

Then change the last line to say:

```
Prompt=never
```