# How to stop (or start) update manager from startup

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make Update Manager stop opening automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85226/how-do-i-make-update-manager-stop-opening-automatically)

I cannot stop the update manager notifying in the startup. How to disable it from startup? I searched in startup applications, but no update manager is listed. Also not in software sources. I'm using 11.10

Comment: See also related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/85226/how-do-i-make-update-manager-stop-opening-automatically