# How do I make Update Manager stop opening automatically?

Tags: update-manager

Update Manager keeps opening automatically and it's getting very annoying, especially when I'm using Gnome Shell. How do I make it stop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may work for you. I haven't verified if it works in GNOME.

- Open the *Software Sources* application.
- Select the "Updates" tab.
- For the "Automatically check for updates" option, select **Never**.

[image: Picture of Software Sources window, with cursor selecting *Never* for 'Automatically check for updates' option]

After this, you will have to open the Update Manager application manually.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work except when I did a apt-get operation but I think it was because of apt-get update.

Comment: This makes it not update itself, but the GUI will still be popping up if anything else causes an update (e.g. like manually running apt-get update.)

Comment: Note, this application is now called "Software & Updates".

Comment: Any way to do this from the command line?

Answer (score 9):

I found [this post](http://lifehacker.com/5295449/disable-ubuntus-annoying-update-manager-popup) with the following instruction:

> open `gconf-editor`, browse down to `Apps` -> `Update Notifier`, and uncheck the `auto_launch` option

---

OK, try [this one](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/10/how-to-view-and-disable-hidden-startup.html).  It's similar to the other answer but disables it instead of deleting it entirely.  It might be safer for you to open the file in an editor and change the line by hand instead of the `sed` command that post uses.

The procedure, using an editor:

1. Open a terminal
2. Move to the autostart directory (`cd /etc/xdg/autostart`) and list the files there (`ls`).
3. Find the startup program you want to run (in our case `update-notifier.desktop`) and open it in an editor (`gksudo gedit update-notifier.desktop`).  Enter your password if necessary.
4. Be careful not to change anything except this line.  Find this line:
   `NoDisplay=true`
    and change it to:
   `NoDisplay=false`
5. Save the file and exit.
6. Reboot to make sure it worked.

Comment: In a single command:
`sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/update-notifier.desktop`

Answer (score 5):

In Precise, it is done using dconf now rather than gconf.

1. Install `dconf-tools`

   $ sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
2. run dconf-editor and navigate to com > ubuntu > update-notifier.
3. Tick `no-show-notifications`

[image: dconf-editor]

And here's how to do it from the command line:

```
dconf write /com/ubuntu/update-notifier/no-show-notifications true
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Ubuntu 16.04. The process that starts that update notifier is `/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/update-manager --no-update --no-focus-on-map`. I'm considering writing a startup script to kill this process.

Answer (score 5):

## Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

The **Update Manager** pops up when it detects a new update. This behaviour can be pretty annoying for many, especially when you are in the midst of your work. To make it worst, if you close it without updating, it will keep on popping up in regular intervals and each time after boot, until you have upgraded your system. To turn it off:

### Method 1 - Disable Update Notifier from autostart

The **Update Notifier** autostarts on boot and triggers Update Manager. In this method, we prevent the Update Notifier itself from autostarting,so that Update Manager won't be triggered. Edit Update Notifier's entry in systemwide autostarts - `/etc/xdg/autostart/update-notifier.desktop` ( Note that you wont be able to use the Startup Applications app,as it only deals with per-user autostart entries ) and add the following line:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
```

Reboot now, and you'll find that there's no Update Notification.

[image: Disable Update Manager Popup]

**Disadvantage:** This disables automatic **Update Notifications** altogether.You'll have to manually check for updates(which is fine by me,but may not be for some people)

### Method 2 - Show Update Indicator

This option makes the Update Notifier show an **Update Indicator** in the panel, instead of popping up the Update Manager. I think this should be the default setting for Update Notifier in Ubuntu. To do it:

**Graphical Way:** Open dconf Editor. Navigate to ***com->ubuntu->update-notifier***. Uncheck the entry `auto-launch` and close dconf Editor. To recover the Update Manager popup function, simply repeat the above step, but place a check in the `auto-launch` entry.
[image: Prevent Update Manager Popup]

**Command Way:** For the terminal lovers out there, type in these commands to do the same.

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier auto-launch false
```

and to recover:

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier auto-launch true
```

These methods were tested and found to be working on **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** with *update-manager* version 0.156.14.11. I got the idea from the post [How to Remove The Annoying Update manager Pop-up in Ubuntu Jaunty](http://www.maketecheasier.com/remove-the-annoying-update-manager-pop-up-in-ubuntu-jaunty/) and simply modified it to work on **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** aka **Precise Pangolin**

Answer (score 1):

In order to **stop** Update Manager from launching:

```
gconftool -s --type bool /apps/update-notifier/auto_launch false
```

To **activate** it again:

```
gconftool -s --type bool /apps/update-notifier/auto_launch true
```

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Edit  `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set:

`Prompt=never` change this with your favorite editor.

Never use `update-manager` with -d this checks whether the next release is available or not.

Answer (score -1):

Should be

```
gconftool -s --type bool /apps/update-notifier/auto_launch false
```

Comment: Didn't work. Thanks anyway though!

Comment: Perhaps this works on Ubuntu versions [prior to 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/a/125273/22949).