# " corrupted filesystem tarfile - corrupted package archive" while processing a deb package

Tags: apt, dpkg

I keep getting the following message:

```
Check if you are using third-party repositories. If so, disable them, because they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore, run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
```

I have no idea how to disable third-party repositories, or even that I had them. I also encounter the same problem every time I try `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libflite1_1.4-release-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 corrupted filesystem tarfile - corrupted package archive
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libflite1_1.4-release-2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try this method here http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/11/fix-package-system-broken-error-ubuntu-10-0410-10-maverick-meerkat/. Are you using any additional PPA , try disabling it from update manager settings in Software source as [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) and run  the command you mentioned in question.

Comment: I think that tutorial is outdated. How do I access "System"?

Comment: Try removing the corrupted package with `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libflite1_1.4-release-2_i386.deb`.

Comment: "System" ????, you can refer the Software sources in [Answers screenshots](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41290/how-to-make-update-manager-stop-nagging-about-a-new-release) , there in "software column" you can see third party repositories.

Answer (score 3):

This is normally due to an incomplete download or some sort of manipulation of the deb file without the proper tools. Removing the package and trying again would solve the issue:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score -1):

install ubuntu tweak to disable third party repos

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libflite1_1.4-release-2_i386.
sudo purge libflite1_1.4-release-2_i386
sudo apt clean && sudo auto-remove
```

Comment: Please give details on the Ubuntu tweak recommendation, and explain the commands. The first command looks unnecessary to me. Why would the OP need to purge `libflite1`, surely he wants it to be installed?